# Auto reverse cross-selling products

Tags: cross-sells

When I setup cross-sell for Product A with Product B, I want it to automatically cross-sell in reverse when saving the product. How can I set this up?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to build an observer and watch the event `catalog_product_save_after`. There you'll be able to retrieve the product you saved, get its cross-sell products, and add your saved product to their cross-sell products.

Be careful when doing this, make sure you don't do it when a product is already present in a product's cross-sell products or you'll end up looping indefinitely.

Comment: I'm not that good in coding unfortunatly. Can you guide me through the steps?

Comment: Look up "creating a module in Magento", "Creating an Observer" and then hook your observer on that event.